# Location.getAltitude() starts returning identical invalid values after a certain time period

Tags: android, gps, location, position, altitude

I need your help.
I wrote a very simple Android widget that shows the altitude which I get in the onLocationChanged method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double myAltitude = -99;
    if (location.hasAltitude()) {
        myAltitude = location.getAltitude();
        Log.d("SAT-LOG","Current Altitude is : "+myAltitude);
        Log.d("SAT-LOG","Current Coordinatees : "+location.getLatitude()+"-"+location.getLongitude());
    }
    ...
}
```

Here how I request the location update:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(gnssActivity);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, gnssActivity);
```

I also tried this:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(gnssActivity);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(1000,1,criteria,gnssActivity,null);
```

I noticed that location.hasAltitude() is always true.
After 10/15 minutes the value is stuck: location.getAltitude() returns the same value until the device reboot (for the record I am using a car tablet).
Instead, the location latitude/longitude are always correct.

I took some log in order to share the behavior:

```
Timestamp            Coordinates        Altitude/Elevation
13:52:51.989    37.6911584,15.1052294   577,6
13:52:52.981    37.691106,15.1052072    576,6
13:52:53.990    37.6910536,15.1051881   576,3
13:52:54.985    37.6910032,15.1051709   576,1
13:52:56.019    37.6909561,15.1051632   575,4
13:52:57.032    37.6909104,15.1051537   573,7
13:52:57.993    37.6908579,15.105138    572,6
13:52:58.984    37.6908022,15.105121    572,1
13:52:59.982    37.690747,15.1051034    571,5
13:53:00.984    37.6906914,15.1050854   571,2
13:53:02.021    37.6906406,15.1050694   571,9
13:53:02.974    37.6906027,15.1050565   572,2
13:53:03.983    37.6905802,15.1050451   621,7000122 <-Invalid Values
13:53:04.984    37.6905657,15.1050349   621,7000122
13:53:05.985    37.6905537,15.1050258   621,7000122
13:53:06.990    37.6905363,15.1050178   621,7000122
13:53:07.982    37.6905103,15.1050077   621,7000122
13:53:08.981    37.6904757,15.1049966   621,7000122
13:53:10.027    37.6904339,15.1049828   615,6000366
13:53:10.982    37.6903825,15.1049643   615,6000366
13:53:11.982    37.6903202,15.1049418   615,6000366
13:53:12.980    37.6902507,15.104916    615,6000366
13:53:14.021    37.6901782,15.1048888   615,6000366
13:53:14.988    37.690104,15.10486      615,6000366
13:53:15.985    37.6900287,15.1048412   615,6000366
13:53:16.990    37.6899508,15.1048195   615,6000366
...
...
...
13:54:34.982    37.6830799,15.1036726   615,6000366
13:54:35.986    37.6829489,15.1036597   615,6000366
13:54:36.984    37.6828161,15.1036388   615,6000366
13:54:37.988    37.6826812,15.1036125   615,6000366 <- Invalid Values ends here
13:54:38.985    37.6825483,15.1035831   551,6 <-Valid Values again
13:54:39.989    37.6824177,15.1035502   551,6
13:54:40.986    37.6822904,15.1035137   551,7
13:54:41.989    37.6821635,15.1034749   551,5
13:54:42.980    37.6820341,15.1034429   551,9
13:54:43.986    37.6818938,15.1034188   551,4
13:54:44.986    37.6817466,15.1034      551,1
```

As you can see from 13:53:03.983 to 13:54:37.988 the methods returns invalid altitude values (the coordinates are right). More or less, 95 invalid samples (consecutive). In the log at 14:04 I have another sequence of 99 invalid values.

If I open the App GPSTest, I see the correct value of altitude.
Can someone help me to understand the issue ?
Is there a better way to get the altitude/elevation?

Comment: Maybe add the code which you're using to listen for the location updates?

Comment: Your callback method that gets the location how many seconds does it take to repeat?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your replies.
I added the requested code.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Huawei [Location Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-locationkit?ha_source=hms1) may help with your issue.Check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050706106?ha_source=hms1).

You can obtains the altitude of the current location by using Location Kit.

[image]

For Detail,pls kindly refer:

[HWLocation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/hwlocation-0000001051066112-V5?ha_source=hms1)

[getAltitude()](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/hwlocation-0000001051066112-V5#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001051066112__section268714924118?ha_source=hms1)